# getFilter() can search filtered data, cant show original data

Tags: java, android

My filter works fine but does not restore the original data when I emptied my searchEditText.

The only error I get is:

> E / SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE range cannot
>   have zero length.

I have done previous research but most say it is a keyboard-related error so I am confused here why my filter does nothing when I empty the editText, but it can be filtered if I enter some keywords there.

I've tried not only at ADB but also on my device, but it didn't work.

Oh and I tried sending "char" as null but you guessed it, it returns an error:

> on null object reference

**UPDATE 1 :**

according to ADM I've change my code to

**UPDATE 2 :**
I have followed the advice carefully from Alokit Nigam, answer and changed my code to something like this:

```
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchEt);
        searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



             }
            });
```

and my filter to

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                String charString = constraint.toString();

                List<product> productsfiltered;

                Log.i("--->", "performFiltering: "+ charString);

                if (charString.isEmpty()){

                   productsfiltered = productList;

                }

                else {
                    List<product> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (product row : productList){

                        if (row.getnama().toLowerCase().contains(charString)){

                            filtered.add(row);

                        }
                    }

                    productsfiltered = filtered;

                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                filterResults.values = productsfiltered;

                return filterResults;

            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                productList = (ArrayList<product>) results.values;

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };

    }
```

and here's the log

```
I/--->: performFiltering: k
I/--->: performFiltering: ke
I/--->: performFiltering: ked
I/--->: performFiltering: keda
I/--->: performFiltering: kedai
I/--->: performFiltering: keda
I/--->: performFiltering: ked
I/--->: performFiltering: ke
I/--->: performFiltering: k
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
I/--->: performFiltering:
```

Case Closed.

Comment: You not need to pass `null` for `CharSequence` .. Just pass it as It is . And Check its length only . Do the searching in `afterTextChanged` .

Comment: did you debug and check whether your code is working?

Comment: @ADM I have change my code according your advice, and tried it again on ADB. but there's no change still throwing exact error I even added Toast just to make sure.

Comment: @KaranMer I've run in debug mode and watching the debug windows but I can tell the only error is the same as Run windows or LogCat windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make two lists one which contains filtered data and one which contains original data.

And use it like this(this is a demo for contact filter)

```
 ArrayList<ContactModel> contactModels;
ArrayList<ContactModel> contactModels1;
Context context;
SharedPreferences prefs;
DbHelper dbHelper;
public ContactsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactModel> contacts) {
    this.context=context;
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE);
    contactModels=contacts;
    contactModels1=contacts;
    dbHelper=DbHelper.getInstance(context);
}
 public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            Log.i("--->", "performFiltering: "+charSequence);
            List<ContactModel>contactListFiltered;
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                contactListFiltered = contactModels1;
            } else {
                List<ContactModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (ContactModel row : contactModels1) {


                    if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

                contactListFiltered = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            contactModels = (ArrayList<ContactModel>) results.values;

            // refresh the list with filtered data
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Also perform query in onTextChanged() callback.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, please check Update 2 above. and I still have the same problem.

Comment: As I mentioned you have to maintain two lists ,I guess you have not maintained it. Check the edited answer (check two lists defined at top).

Comment: ahh I see, thank you very much for your guidance. now it functions properly.